# Where to put CosmosClient's `CreateAndInitializeAsync` for use in Azure functions?

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have Azure functions (trigger functions) that connect to Cosmos Db to do some work.

I want to pre-warm those operations by calling `CreateAndInitializeAsync` on ComsosClient so that 1st request would not be slow.

However I am struggling on where to put `CreateAndInitializeAsync`.
On one hand it cannot be put in the DI initialization because its a long running task.

On the other hand there is no generic StartUp or Initialize method which would be a good place to put such an initialization code.

How and where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `IHostedService` to call a method to do a warm up:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
        s.AddSingleton<IExampleService, MyExampleService>();
        s.AddHostedService<WarmUpService>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


public class WarmUpService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IExampleService _service;

    public WarmUpService(IExampleService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //implement your own logic. No need to await
        await _service.GetMetadataAsync();
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //no implementation
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here's an example of how your service could look like. In the example the constructor sets up the client and container, but no calls are made yet. The constructor has all the logic required to properly initialize an instance of the service. So there's also no danger of forgetting to call an `Initialize' method.

I've added a `WarmUpAsync` whose purpose is to do an actual call to Cosmos to initialize the connection, although it could be any existing method that does a simple request to the Cosmos database.

```cs
public class CosmosExampleService : IExampleService
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly CosmosClient _client;

    public CosmosStateService(IOptions<CosmosSettings> options)
    {
        var settings = options.Value;
        _client = new CosmosClient(settings.Endpoint, settings.Key);
        _container = _client.GetContainer(settings.Database, settings.Container);
    }

    public async Task<Question> WarmUpAsync()
    {
        //basic call to warm up the service
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's an interesting idea. So you are saying I should be calling `await CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync(cosmosDbConnectionString, containers, options);` in the `WarmUpService.StartAsync()` method?

Comment: This seems to be working to run on start of the service indeed. Now the only problem is how to use that returned instance as a Singleton throughout the application....

Comment: @Tanuki not sure what you mean. In the example above the `IExampleService` is registered as singleton. You can call that service from any constructor like you normally would using Dependency Injection. As example of a constructor containing function triggers `public MyFunctions(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IExampleService service)`.

Comment: Oh, I meant cosmos client instance. `CreateAndInitializeAsync()` returns an initialised instance that you are supposed to use going forwards. I didn't realise this until I tested your suggestion (I thought just running `CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync()`  would do the trick).

Comment: I've added an example of what the service could look like with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**CreateAndInitializeAsync** method is used when you want to set up the Cosmos DB environment before performing operations in your Azure Functions. It is used in the initialize method in below code. In this it checks whether the Cosmos DB client is already initialized or not. If not then it acquires a lock to ensure thread safety.

Within the lock,  it checks again if initialization is still required to avoid redundant initialization. If initialization is needed, it calls the `CreateAndInitializeAsync` method to initialize the Cosmos DB client.

In below code an example document is created, and this document is saved to both the second and third containers using the `CreateItemAsync` method.

As per [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.createandinitializeasync?view=azure-dotnet) `CreateAndInitializeAsync` method is used in the below code, it consists of `connectionString` and `containers` as parameters.

```cs
public static class HttpFunction
{
    private static bool isInitialized = false;
    private static readonly object initializationLock = new object();
    private static CosmosClient cosmosClient;

    [FunctionName("HttpFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        Initialize();

        try
        {
            await PerformCosmosDbOperation(log);

            return new OkObjectResult("Cosmos DB operation completed successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError("Function execution failed: {ex.Message}");
            return new ObjectResult("Internal Server Error") { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError };
        }
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            lock (initializationLock)
            {
                if (!isInitialized)
                {
                    var connectionString = "*****";
                    var containers = new List<(string databaseId, string containerId)>
                    {
                        ("newDb", "secondCont"),
                        ("newDb","thirdContainer")
                    };
                   CreateAndInitializeAsync(connectionString, containers).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task CreateAndInitializeAsync(
        string connectionString,
        IReadOnlyList<(string databaseId, string containerId)> containers)
    {
        cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString);

        foreach (var (databaseId, containerId) in containers)
        {
            await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseId);
            await cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseId).CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, "/id", 400);
        }

        await Task.Delay(5000); 
    }

    private static async Task PerformCosmosDbOperation(ILogger log)
    {
        var secondContainerId = "secondCont";
        var thirdContainerId = "thirdContainer";

        var secondContainer = cosmosClient.GetContainer("newDb", secondContainerId);
        var thirdContainer = cosmosClient.GetContainer("newDb", thirdContainerId);

        var document = new { id = Guid.NewGuid(), name = "Example Document" };

        await secondContainer.CreateItemAsync(document);

        await thirdContainer.CreateItemAsync(document);

        log.LogInformation("Cosmos DB operation completed.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**
In Browser:
Cosmos DB operation completed successfully.

In Azure Cosmos DB Container:

```js
secondCont:
{
    "id": "d279d070-8e4d-4b71-8ccb-658024e66c38",
    "name": "Example Document"
}

thirdContainer:
{
    "id": "d279d070-8e4d-4b71-8ccb-658024e66c38",
    "name": "Example Document"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed demonstration, however Initialize on trigger is defeating the point. I would like to pre-warm Function on initialise, so that 1st call to that function wouldn't be taking tens of seconds. Also first call to Cosmos DB does initialise anyway, which is why I am looking to do `CreateAndInitializeAsync` outside of first call at some kind of function start up equivalent. Also, not sure lock is necessary as it is not a multithreaded application.